# Error when trying to install Python brute

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to install `pip install brute` but I got an error message:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Failed
> to parse: https://username:password@proxyserver:proxyport

Does anyone know about this? Could you help me?

Comment: your network is in the proxy. so try to access the proxy with username and password or remove the proxy then install

Answer (score 1):

You could try `pip3 install brute`